# Getting null when using getString with JSONObject class on Android

Tags: android, json

I have the following code:

```
JSONObject student2 = new JSONObject();
    try {
        student2.put("name", "NAME OF STUDENT2");

        System.out.println(student2.get("name"));
        System.out.println(student2.getString("name"));

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I was just trying to create an JSONObject and extract the "name" value from it.

But the two "System.out.println" commands returns null. I expect the string "NAME OF STUDENT2" as a result.

What I was doing wrong?

Comment: this piece of code is working fine. i think your problem is somewhere else

Comment: There is no stack trace because this code didn't generate an error. It only results in a null response.

Comment: this code works fine. you may have issues with your environment.

Comment: @fabiobh your code is 100% correct, check in logcat properly or try in another device. I think issue is only in logs not printing. So try to disconnect device and check again or try in another device. check this https://i.stack.imgur.com/xB9r4.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
try {
     JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject("{\"name\":\"NAME OF STUDENT2\"}");
     System.out.println(jsonObject.getString("name"));

}catch (JSONException err){
     Log.d("Error", err.toString());
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *how* and/or *why* it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: This solution is something that I want to avoid. The Json needs to be written entirely in one block of code. When it's only one parameter, it's easy to write, but if you need to write 10 parameters in the Json, it will be a mess.